# Forbidden words checker

Tags: javascript, arrays, include

i'm new on stack but here's my question:

I'm trying to check if an html input's value has one of my forbidden words that are in a array.

I've tried:

1. Using split(), transforming the input.value in a array and then comparing each other.
2. Using toString() to transform the array into a string, and then comparing both.
3. Using a string with all the words ("wordone wordtwo wordthree") instead an array(["wordone","wordtwo", "wordthree"]).
4. Spliting the string above then comparing.
5. And some variants of the examples above, but always checking with includes() method.

I'm really not understanding why nothing works.

> When i put only one forbidden word in the array, it works.

> If i write more than one word on the input element, even if there's only one word in the array, it not works.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input id="field" type="text" size="100">
<button id="check">check</button>
<p id="announce">Message</p>
```

Here's the JS:

```
    fieldIncludes() {

    let field = document.querySelector('#field'); //gets the field
    let btn = document.querySelector('#check'); //gets the check-field button
    let messageBox = document.querySelector('#announce'); // gets the <p> to show a message

    let forbiddenWords = ['wordOne', 'wordTwo', 'wordThree'];

    btn.addEventListener("click", () =>  {

        if (field.value.includes(forbiddenWords)){

            messageBox.innerHTML = "Forbidden!";

        } else {
            messageBox.innerHTML = "Okay :)";
        }

    })

}
```

*Please ignore that the JS is in a class.*

Comment: Note that case will matter also. `"Foo bar".includes('foo')` will be false but `"Foo bar".toLowerCase().includes('foo')` will be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `includes()` should be a single string to check, it doesn't automatically loop over the array. You can use the `.some()` method to check if any of them match.

```
if (forbiddenWords.some(word => field.value.includes(word))) {
    messageBox.innerHTML = "Forbidden!";
} else {
    messageBox.innerHTML = "Okay";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hope i didn't get you wrong.

```
    var str = 'you plays like a noob';
    
    function inspect_string(str, arr){
        flag = false; 
        arr.forEach(ar=>{
            flag = str.match(new RegExp(ar)) ? true : false;
        });
        return flag
    }
    
    // var arr = ['noob', 'trash'];
    var arr = ['nice', 'good'];
    console.log(inspect_string(str, arr));
```